# JQuery скрипт начинает работать только после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

Есть код который размещен в body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //Выравниваем текст с изображением на главной странице
    jQuery(".fu_third_section_img", this).each(function(){
        var height = jQuery(this).height();
        jQuery(".fu_third_section_text").css("height", height);
    });
});
</script>
```

который выравнивает поле с текстом по высоте загруженной картинки(wordpress):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="fu_third_section_text">
            <h2><?php echo get_option('woo_fu_name_dostoprim1'); ?></h2>
            <span><?php echo get_option('woo_fu_text_dostoprim1'); ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="fu_third_section_img">
            <img src="<?php echo get_option('woo_fu_image_dostoprim1'); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

При первой загрузке скрипт не срабатывает. Начинает работать только после перезагрузки страницы. В консоли только JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1 . Вот сайт http://barbaris-kzn.ru . Помогите плиз!

Answer (score 2):

Есть подозрение, что картинки не успевают загрузиться. Варианты решения:

1) Используйте [`load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) вместо [`ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). `Ready()` означает загрузку страницы, но не картинок в ней.

2) Укажите размеры картинок в теге `<img>`:

```
 <img src=".." width=1200 heigth=600>
```

Comment: Поменял на ` jQuery(window).load(function() {...});` Не помогло. Вообще перестало подгонять по высоте. Пробовал даже плагин waitForImages, тоже не выходит.

Comment: А задавать высоту  с помощью height нет возможности потому-что хотелось бы сохранить адаптивность.